# Leap year script, return false everytime

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code to check if the year is leap or not, but it returns false every time.

```
<script src="dateLibrary.js"> </script>
<script>
function myLeapYearFunction(aDate)
{
var year = parseFloat(window.prompt("Enter a year: "));
var aDate = new Date(year);
document.write("is it leap? " + isLeapYear(aDate));
}
myLeapYearFunction();
</script>
```

dateLibrary.js

```
function isLeapYear(aDate)
/*********************************************************************/
/* Argument is a Date object. Function returns the boolean value     */
/* true if the year is a leap year. False otherwise,                 */
/*********************************************************************/

{
var year = aDate.getFullYear();
if (((year % 4) == 0) && ((year % 100)!=0) || ((year % 400) == 0))
    return (true)
else
    return (false)
}; 
/*************************End of function*****************************/
```

I have been trying for 4 hours now and could not find the mistake.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try logging the result of `new Date(year)`. Hint: it’s not treated as a year.

Comment: Try an extra set of braces like I have done here `(((year % 4) == 0) && ((year % 100)!=0))` as this is one condition as a whole.

Comment: @AakashVerma Should not be needed due to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Exactly, I am sorry. I thought it was the other way round. Although I don't understand why he cannot directly take year with some regex validation.

Comment: setYear would be possible, like shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do as few changes as possible:

```
<script src="dateLibrary.js"> </script>
<script>
function myLeapYearFunction(aDate)
{
var year = parseFloat(window.prompt("Enter a year: "));
// initialize without year and set year afterwards.
var aDate = new Date();
aDate.setYear(year);
document.write("is it leap? " + isLeapYear(aDate));
}
myLeapYearFunction();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `Date` object since you're just testing the year and not the date.

Other unrelated changes include using `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat`, and refactoring your `isLeapYear` function a tad.

```js
function myLeapYearFunction() {
   var year = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a year: "));
   console.log("is it leap? " + isLeapYear(year));
}

myLeapYearFunction();

function isLeapYear(year) {
   var fourth = year % 4 == 0;
   var hundredth = year % 100 == 0;
   var fourHundredth = year % 400 == 0;
   return fourth && (!hundredth || fourHundredth);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using:

```
var aDate = new Date();
var year = aDate.getFullYear();
document.write("is it leap? " + isLeapYear(year));
```

instead.

- as Date() class does not take any "year" argument
- There are 4 ways of initiating a date:

  1. new Date()
  2. new Date(milliseconds)
  3. new Date(dateString)
  4. new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)